# Retrieve data from a text file with dynamic values

Tags: python, string, file

I have a text file which gives me the metrics of the etcd cluster. The file is like this (only a portion):

```
# TYPE go_memstats_frees_total counter
go_memstats_frees_total 967077
# HELP go_memstats_gc_sys_bytes Number of bytes used for garbage collection system metadata.
# TYPE go_memstats_gc_sys_bytes gauge
go_memstats_gc_sys_bytes 724992
# HELP go_memstats_heap_alloc_bytes Number of heap bytes allocated and still in use.
# TYPE go_memstats_heap_alloc_bytes gauge
go_memstats_heap_alloc_bytes 6.113376e+06
# HELP go_memstats_heap_idle_bytes Number of heap bytes waiting to be used.
# TYPE go_memstats_heap_idle_bytes gauge
go_memstats_heap_idle_bytes 3.8912e+06
# HELP go_memstats_heap_inuse_bytes Number of heap bytes that are in use.
# TYPE go_memstats_heap_inuse_bytes gauge
go_memstats_heap_inuse_bytes 8.298496e+06
# HELP go_memstats_heap_objects Number of allocated objects.
# TYPE go_memstats_heap_objects gauge
go_memstats_heap_objects 22386
# HELP go_memstats_heap_released_bytes_total Total number of heap bytes released to OS.
# TYPE go_memstats_heap_released_bytes_total counter
go_memstats_heap_released_bytes_total 0
# HELP go_memstats_heap_sys_bytes Number of heap bytes obtained from system.
# TYPE go_memstats_heap_sys_bytes gauge
go_memstats_heap_sys_bytes 1.2189696e+07
# HELP go_memstats_last_gc_time_seconds Number of seconds since 1970 of last garbage collection.
# TYPE go_memstats_last_gc_time_seconds gauge
go_memstats_last_gc_time_seconds 1.5306874009185588e+09
# HELP go_memstats_lookups_total Total number of pointer lookups.
# TYPE go_memstats_lookups_total counter
go_memstats_lookups_total 4213
# HELP go_memstats_mallocs_total Total number of mallocs.
# TYPE go_memstats_mallocs_total counter
go_memstats_mallocs_total 989463
# HELP go_memstats_mcache_inuse_bytes Number of bytes in use by mcache structures.
# TYPE go_memstats_mcache_inuse_bytes gauge
go_memstats_mcache_inuse_bytes 69440
# HELP go_memstats_mcache_sys_bytes Number of bytes used for mcache structures obtained from system.
# TYPE go_memstats_mcache_sys_bytes gauge
go_memstats_mcache_sys_bytes 81920
# HELP go_memstats_mspan_inuse_bytes Number of bytes in use by mspan structures.
# TYPE go_memstats_mspan_inuse_bytes gauge
go_memstats_mspan_inuse_bytes 106096
# HELP go_memstats_mspan_sys_bytes Number of bytes used for mspan structures obtained from system.
# TYPE go_memstats_mspan_sys_bytes gauge
go_memstats_mspan_sys_bytes 131072
# HELP go_memstats_next_gc_bytes Number of heap bytes when next garbage collection will take place.
# TYPE go_memstats_next_gc_bytes gauge
go_memstats_next_gc_bytes 1.1043536e+07
# HELP go_memstats_other_sys_bytes Number of bytes used for other system allocations.
# TYPE go_memstats_other_sys_bytes gauge
go_memstats_other_sys_bytes 4.284883e+06
# HELP go_memstats_stack_inuse_bytes Number of bytes in use by the stack allocator.
# TYPE go_memstats_stack_inuse_bytes gauge
go_memstats_stack_inuse_bytes 4.063232e+06
# HELP go_memstats_stack_sys_bytes Number of bytes obtained from system for stack allocator.
# TYPE go_memstats_stack_sys_bytes gauge
go_memstats_stack_sys_bytes 4.063232e+06
```

I want to retrieve the allocated heap bytes and the inuse heap bytes from the file snd then see if the inuse heap percentage is greater than 75. The metrics change dynamically. How to retrieve both the data using Python? These are the first instance of them in the file. Also how to calculate the percentage when bytes are on this format:

```
go_memstats_heap_alloc_bytes 6.113376e+06
go_memstats_heap_inuse_bytes 8.298496e+06
```

Comment: Is the pattern of the file going to change?

Comment: @ThatBird The pattern is not going to change. Only the values. Also I am not able to find how to calculate the value in Python when the Euler's number is involved.

Comment: You want the number in float?

Comment: How often do you want the changed values?

Comment: @Mufeed Yes. Also how to retrieve the two numbers. Retrieve and then convert to float.

Comment: @ThatBird that my function is taking care of.

Comment: Did you try using [decimal](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your pattern never changes:

```
import re

with open("something.txt", "r") as fd:
    for line in fd:
        # you can use line.startswith("go_memstats_heap_alloc_bytes") too
        if re.match("go_memstats_heap_alloc_bytes", line):   # search for the pattern using regular expression
            heap_allocated_bytes = float(line.split()[1])   # get the matched line, split it into two, extract second value
            print("go_memstats_heap_alloc_bytes",heap_allocated_bytes)
        elif re.match("go_memstats_heap_inuse_bytes", line):
            heap_inuse_bytes = float(line.split()[1])
            print("go_memstats_heap_inuse_bytes",heap_inuse_bytes)
```

**Output**:

```
go_memstats_heap_alloc_bytes 6113376.0
go_memstats_heap_inuse_bytes 8298496.0
```

Comment: Thanks. Just one question. The float value is 6113376.0 and the value in file is 6.113376e+06. What is the difference?

Comment: Both are same. The one with e is scientifc notation. It is used to represent very small numbers.

Comment: It is useful when you want to represent very small numbers like 0.0000443400

Comment: You probably don't need regex here. A simple string match should suffice

Comment: yes. string.startswith() would have been sufficient